# Networking Docker Compose

Tags: docker-compose

I have 2 services that should be aware of each other and 2 databases (1 for each). So I have created the following file as link cannot bidirectional. But it fails. server1 doesn' see server 2,

```
version: '2'
services:
  server1:
    image: ...
    depends_on:
      - server1_db  
    networks:
      - server1_network
      - server2_network
  server1_db:
    image: ...
    networks:
      - server1_network
  server2:
    image: ...
    depends_on:
      - server2_db
    networks:
      - server1_network
      - server2_network
  server2_db:
    image: mongo:latest
    networks:
      - server2_network
networks:
  server1_network:
  server2_network:
```

did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not the problem : java URI object is not handling correctly URI with a hostname without a dot.

In my case I have an URI with a port number like server1:82 and URI getPort() returns -1 .

Once I figure this out, everything went back to normal...

see [Connecting to Meteor DDP from Java with Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281890/connecting-to-meteor-ddp-from-java-with-docker-container/40281892#40281892)